# Set Analysis on dimension - Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to select those projects, whose sum of revenues are between a range (vRevenueMin, vRevenueMax)

I have tried the below equation,  but is not working for me.

aggr(ONLY({=$(vRevenueMin)<=$(vRevenueMax)"}>}project_name),project_name)

Data format :

project_name, RevenueAmount

A, 100

A, 70

B, 30

C, 10

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

=aggr(only({=$(=vRevenueMin)<=$(=vRevenueMax)"}>}project_name),project_name)